# deselect items in a list dashcode

Tags: iphone, macos, mobile-safari, dashcode

i'm currently struggling how to deselect a item in list, when pressing the back button. So how can set the selection state when returning to the previous view.
Thanks in advance.
Cheers
Simon

Comment: Do you mean a TableView when speaking about a list?

Comment: No i mean the list, which is used when developing a web app for mobile safari (dashcode).

Answer (score 0):

This will select the first item in the list. As lists allow multiple selections you need to pass an array. I am not sure how you deselect the list entirely.

```
document.getElementById("list").object.setSelectionIndexes([0]);
```